# Calculate T-Test, P_val value using two columns from dataframe in R

Tags: r, shiny, p-value, t-test

While calculating `T_test` and `P_val` values using two result columns from one data frame I am getting the error below:

```
Getting Error in : All columns in a tibble must be vectors. 
Column `T_Test` is a `htest` object.
```

My Code

```
library(tibble)
statsdata <- statsdata %>%
    add_column(T_Test = t.test(x = statsdata$Result1, y = statsdata$Result,
                               alternative = "two.sided",
                               mu = 0, paired = FALSE, var.equal = TRUE,
                               conf.level = 0.95), .after = "Mean_Column")
  
statsdata <- statsdata %>%
        add_column(P_val = t.test(x = commontestsummary$Result1, y = commontestsummary$Result2,
                                         alternative = "two.sided",
                                         mu = 0, paired = FALSE, var.equal = TRUE,
                                         conf.level = 0.95)$p.val, .after = "T_test")
```

Can someone please guide me on how to resolve this error? statsdata is a data frame. I am unable to identify the exact issue.

Comment: The output `t.test()` is not a simple value, you will need to parse this output. For example `t.test(**your test**)$p.value` will return the p value.

Comment: Thank you so much Dave2e, now I am able to get p_val value in the table in column but it is the same value across all categories. Can I group_by and get a separate p_val value based on the groups(category) in R

Comment: What categories?  Yes maybe, Without seeing what your data looks like nor what your intended objective I can't provide any meaningful additions.  I suggest closing this question and asking a new one.